# How can I automatically tether on Macbook when I don't have wifi?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, tethering

Is there a way that I can detect that my mac does not have a wifi connection and automatically use my iPhone tethering without I have to go a select it from the menu?

Answer (score 2):

The priority given by your Mac to the various connections are determined by the order of services listed in your Network settings. To view this:

- Go to System Preferences > Network:

[image]

So the best way to achieve what you want is to use a USB connection for your iPhone tethering and then change the order as follows:

1. Click on the Cog/Gear icon (on the right of the minus '-' sign at bottom left)
2. Select **Set Service Order...**
3. In the Service Order window that appears, click and drag the Wi-Fi connection so it is at the top and then move your iPhone USB connection so that it’s second)
4. Click OK
5. Exit System Preferences

Now, if your Mac has no Wi-Fi connection it’ll go to the next one in your Service order to see if that’s available and so on.

**Note:** You don’t have to use a USB connection for your iPhone tethering, however I recommend this as it has the extra benefits of keeping your iPhone charged and ensures a stable connection.